# how does the recursive template deduction works

Tags: c++, c++17, recursive-templates

I read some complex template class design, it looks like recirsive template deduction with template parameter refers to the template itself.
I simplified the codes as follow, does anybody can help explain how the template deduction works for the follow codes.
also I want to know more knowledge about the programming technique used in this demo and can you share me any c++ standard material about this topic.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename X = char, class T = int>
class ABC;

template<class X, class T>
class ABC <X, ABC<X, T>>{
public:
    T t;
};


template<class T, class M>
class ABC : public ABC<T, ABC<T,M>> {};

int main() {
    ABC<int, char> abc;
    abc.t = 1;
    ABC<> abcd;
    abcd.t = 3;
    std::cout << abc.t << " " << abcd.t << std::endl;
}
```

as shown above, I tried simplified the code and write a little demo.
my compiler is gcc 9.4.0 released with ubuntu20, with compile args -std=c++17.

What I concerned most is how abc or abcd is deduced as ABC<T, M> is inherited from ABC<T, ABC<T, M>>, and ABC<T, M> seems is a self-referencing template class?

And also how the template deduction terminated as it seems there is only a template class declaration `template<typename X = char, class T = int> class ABC;` and seems no implemention of it.

abc.t is print as unvisable char succeeding with a whitespace and then a charater 3, as below.

```
 3
```

Comment: There is no "template deduction" of any kind going on here.

Comment: You simplified some complex looking code. Please show the complex looking code. Your code doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `std::cout << char(1) << " " << int(3)`. as `abc.t` is of type `char`. In other words, you are printing an unprintable ASCII character; that's why you can't see it in the output. Make it `abc.t = '!'`;` and you'll [see it printed](https://godbolt.org/z/98sxq5j3a)

Comment: OK， thanks a lot about explanation about the printed whitespace caused by char.  But the problem I concerned more is how ABC<int, char> is deduced.  it seems there is  a self-referring template class ABC and a inherited template class also called ABC

Comment: This is just partial specialization... You first have a primary template declaration, then a partial specialization of that template, then the primary template definition. There is no recursion taking place.

Comment: @ildjarn How is a template using itself as a type parameter (`template<class X, class T>
class ABC <X, ABC<X, T>>`) not recursive?

Comment: I also wondering why  template<class X, class T> class ABC <X, ABC<X, T>> {}; is not a self-referencing  recursive template?   now I understand that template<class T, class M>class ABC is a subclass(with template parameters not deduced) of the partial specialized template class ABC<X, ABC<X, M>>, but how template<class X, class T> class ABC <X, ABC<X, T>> {}; works properly

Comment: @Peter : The primary template is not using itself as a type parameter – it is unconditionally using the partial specialization, which is effectively a different template (it has a different definition after all).

Comment: @ildjarn That may all be true, but isn't `template<class X, class T> class ABC <X, ABC<X, T>>` recursive?

Comment: @Peter : Again, no, that is simply a specialization for cases where the 2nd template argument supplied happens to itself be an `ABC`. This is closer to pattern matching than recursion (but is not strictly 'matching' because partial ordering is a thing). `std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>` is not recursion either.

Comment: @ildjarn I got another question, is ABC<int, char> deduced from the partial specialized template, or is it deduced from the primary template? If it is deduced from the primary version, we got a ABC<int, char> who is a subclass of ABC<int, ABC<int, char>> and ABC<int, ABC<int, char> is deduced from the partial specialized template with X=int and T=char, so the partial specialized template is instantiate to template<> ABC<int, ABC<int, char>> {char t;};  Is that right?

Comment: `ABC<int, char>` instantiates the primary template (whose declaration is on line 3-4 of your code and whose definition is on line 13-14); the primary template inherits from the partial specialization, in this case `ABC<int, ABC<int, char>>`. So I think your understanding is correct, it's just terminology that is a problem – as was said by others, there is no deduction taking place here, so continuing to ask about what is "deduced" is only confusing things.

Comment: @ildjarn thanks a lot for your rigorous explanation. I indeed got confused with deduction and instantiation and now I will make my understanding about instantiation and deduction.